# Keep a parent element the same size before and after conditionally showing a button in it with vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, quasar-framework

Using vue.js (and [quasar framework](http://quasar-framework.org/components/card.html)), I have a card component. When an event is triggered a button at the bottom of the card is shown. When the button appears, the size of the card increases due to the height of the button which is added. I find this ugly and would prefer the size of the card to be the same before and after having a button.

I tried with some `<br>` before the button is added to compensate for the height difference, but this is clumsy and does not work properly when I animate the appearance of the button with a fade-in e.g.

As the card(s) will contain various content(size), making a fixed size for card will not really work.

How can I have the same size of my card before and after showing the button?

Comment: Can you add a minimal example in the question to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Can you have the button in the dom already, but set it to visibility hidden? Then instead use the event trigger to add a class to change it to visible and make it active.

Comment: @mthomp Yeah, that might be what I need. But when hidden, it should not react to clicks etc... ?! Will look into this...

Comment: @musicformellons you can use the data you are using to make the button visible, enable the functionality of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix: you must know button height before. Then nest it to element with same height achieved with `min-height` property :

```
<div id="button-container" style="min-height: /* your button height */">
  <button>Hidden yet</button>
</div>
```

It is not very elegant way. Use it only if you are not able to use `visibility: hidden` on button, instead of `display: none`, as @musicformellons suggest in comment.

I think, this example demonstrates your problem:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    canShow: false
  },
  methods: {
    toggleButton () {
      this.canShow = !this.canShow
    }
  },
  created () {
    setInterval(function () {
      this.toggleButton()
    }.bind(this), 500)
  }
})
```

```css
.bordered {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="bordered">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum, bla, bla, bla...</p>
    <button v-if="canShow">I am just troublemaker</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

And I think this is the most elegant, "true Vue way" solution. Moreover, with this solution you need not to know button height before...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    visibility: false
  },
  methods: {
    toggleButton () {
      this.visibility = !this.visibility
    },
    logIt () {
      console.log('button clicked')
    }
  },
  created () {
    setInterval(function () {
      this.toggleButton()
    }.bind(this), 1000)
  }
})
```

```css
.bordered {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.animate-me {
  transition: all .4s;
}
.is-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="bordered">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum, bla, bla, bla...</p>
    <!-- Render it always, but change visibility as needed instead --> 
    <button
      class="animate-me"
      :class="{'is-hidden': visibility}"
      @click="logIt"
      :disabled="visibility"
    >
      I am just troublemaker
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

Comment: @musicformellons Thanx :) But I still think it is ugly solution :)

Comment: I seem not to be the only one with this issue [link] (https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/4998/v-show-possible-for-visibility-hidden-instead-of-display-none) within vue.

Comment: And this one: https://github.com/javisperez/vue-visible    with a nice demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fcpc6utm/

Comment: @musicformellons Yes, because often you can't use visibility instead of display property. Many frameworks rely on changing display property, not just visibilty.

Comment: Why would you not be able to use visibility property?

Comment: @musicformellons You can use it. But manually, as your own solution. Do you want example?

Comment: @musicformellons Done, example of elegant way added. Without knowing the button height, without external plugins. You will like it... :)

Comment: Nice, this is indeed cleaner! How would I get my fade-in&out of the button working now as the hiding and unhiding is instant?

Comment: Yeah, but now -even when not showing the button- it is still there for clicks...!

Comment: @musicformellons Problem fixed... :)

Comment: I had to do `.is-hidden {opacity: 0 !important}` as quasar sets an opacity of 0.6 for disabled button by default styling. It's perfect now, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could give the css of the button `position: absolute` and the card `position: relative`, and then fiddle around with the `bottom; left; top; right;` position settings of the button.